# How do I independently study foundational math relate to current developments?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, large-cardinals

Today I spent hours reading about recent developments regarding the Continuum Hypothesis and Set Theory. Where would I even start with these topics? My undergraduate professors all considered foundational questions to be something noone did anymore.

I earned my BA in Math in 2001. However, as a returning student I needed to focus on completing my general studies. My math electives were waived by my department chair based on my previous actuarial exams. I don't know if I could motivate myself to work through a textbook of proofs. Nor could I evaluate my own work in that regard.

I had one introductory course in Set Theory as an undergraduate. Also, I scraped through Real Analysis, Group Theory and Ring Theory. Perhaps a few other proof based undergraduate courses.

I'm not sure if this is a helpful insight. I had difficulty relating to my classmates because I am not a Platonist. And I am not particularly fond of numbers. I think in terms of patterns and structures. Also, I consider math a development out of our cognitive capabilities of abstraction, not any sort of description of reality.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! I found this quite interesting and I am following up on several items.

Answer (score 0):

:) I think your lecturers are pretty clearly wrong, then. Many people are involved with foundational issues, and there is literature. (Often, by the way, they may be paid by departments of philosophy, as opposed to departments of mathematics.) I have a somewhat similar background in math. Why should you not be able to work through textbooks? I think that's what they are meant for. In any case, do you know st.openlogicproject.org? I am working a bit with this book, I think it's not to bad, you may give it a try, it's for free. Otherwise often Potter (2004) is mentioned. And, depending on your interests, you may want to have a look at the new proof theory book from Mancosu-Galvan-Zach. For in proof theory, that's where it get's *foundational*, as far as I understand. In any case, you may also be inspired by reverse mathematics, category theory and/or type theory.
Last but not least, do you know the Oxford Handbook of philosophy of mathematics and logic? May give you some background for your more philosophical questions..

Comment: I like the link you sent, it seems like it As far as working through proofs, I simply don't trust myself to know if I have really grasped the issues because you often know exactly what the result should be.

Comment: I think I see what you mean...may I ask whether you consider this to be a mathematical or philosophical problem, or both?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Otherwise I would likely not think on this. Perhaps both. And neither! On a simple level, my reasoning might be faulty. I may omit some essential part of a proof. Or, I might consider I need to prove something inessential. (Though I now realize that this forum is a community where I could ask for a critique.) Philosophically, I might get stuck on a concept. Often, I simply do not believe something being shown and cannot work beyond that point. (Somehow this would often evaporate a few days before an examination in school.)

Comment: Historically, much of the math I studied informally was applied math studied specifically to pass my actuarial exams which were highly competitive timed exams and so I mostly studied previous exam questions. I might need to use a Taylor series expansion to calculate a compound interest problem, because calculators were forbidden. In fact, I was unaware that Linear Algebra was something other than the algebra I had learned elsewhere. The exams were highly numerical. It is rare that a calculation error will yeild a correct numerical result.

Comment: Returning to university, my first class was Real Analysis, a "weed out" class at the time. (A class to cull students considered untalented.) I then had difficulties with my coursework transferred from my previous school in a different state. I needed many more general studies courses than anticipated. This resulted in financial pressures. My schooling was paid by a vocational program. I made minimal effort in my Math courses. Also, I diluted my efforts by taking some statistics courses. These fit my actuarial background. My core curriculum was all proof based coursework.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! That's interesting...concerning your doubts when studying proofs, it reminds me a bit of this famous part in Descartes' Meditations when he wonders whether there is some kind of 'bad daemon' in his mind only makeing him 'feel like' he was very sure about something, when really there would be no reason to trust...I've had thoughts of similar kind in the past here and there, but would also admit that this is probably not too common among students of math, as far as I percieved. Overall, it's a pretty 'platonistic crowd' (if I may say so), I guess.

Comment: In any case, I find a skeptical approach generally to be a good advise, though anybody may decide for themselves. During the history, there were, as far as I am informed, again and again all sorts of scepticisms about math... One possible reaction may be to rely on formal systems - have you heard of the so-called 'foundational crisis'? Some people today study proof-checking by computers...would that give you (more) certainity?

Comment: It's sad, I tend to say, when financial considerations determine one's path (through studies). But one or the other way this will be common...even if, as in some contries, studies are largely fund by the government (which then, in turn, may result in less overall study quality, but nevertheless open to almost everybody)..but this may be a political discussion, so I guess we won't dig deeper here in that regard. I started studing quite 'late' in my life (I was around 30), and will maybe return for master-studies next year, then studying and working part-time...

Comment: Perhaps knowing that I am a 63 year old woman in the USA will help explain my lack of confidence. Many men in the 1970's were fearful of women entering their fields and "stealing jobs" from men. Often I was the only woman in my college science classes in the early 1970's in the lab my classmates would not allow me to handle the equipment. (At the time, I was an engineering major.) My mother discouraged me from a higher education. She paid for private higher education for her sons, but not her daughters. Also, I was mercilessly bullied from age 7 to 13 by my classmates.

Comment: Actually, I find comfort in knowing math is not "real." In my physics and engineering classes, we were always approximating results and I was not always clear on whether it was justified. At the time, we were still using printed tables of logarithms and trigonometric functions. I am sure things are taught differently today. Pocket calculators were still very expensive in 1972.

Comment: Hey again and thank you for your openness and honesty! :) I see...well when I studied, a decade ago, there were still not many girls in our classes. Maybe one of four were female in my semester. But at least now the world is, or so it seems to me, very open for women in technical tasks and/or high responsibility. Thats very unfair when girls are not given the equal possibilites...I think nowadays there are many initiatives that want to attract girls to technical subjects. But bullying seems to be still a big problem, maybe it got even worse in the last decades for some reason..

Comment: Of course, 'math and reality' is a big topic, I guess, very very interesting, fascinating. I am surely no expert, not even well-read. In a passage about philosophy of math I read one day that "philosophically, you either explain why/how math actually IS as certain/determined, perhaps even 'real' (in some sense that would have to be explained as well), or at least you give some explanation to why/how it $seems$ to be like that, in case it really isn't"...that wasn't an exact quotation I don't remember exaclty, but it was something along these lines...I found that was not a bad place to start..